# Adjust <li> width to its content's width

Tags: html, css

I have following CSS code:

```
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

nav li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

nav li :hover {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    color: white;
}
```

Which makes elements in my navbar look like this:

[image: without padding/margin/manual width]

But there's actually 4 items, not 6. I'll add some padding in `<li>`:

[image: padding/margin]

But when I hover over the first item, I have this ugly white space from both sides of it. `Margin` does exactly the same thing. Let's remove `margin`/`padding` and set `<li>` width manually to `120px`:

[image: manual width]

First two items are now formatted somehow acceptably, but items `a` and `b` take visually far too much space than necessary. What I aim for would be something like this (made in image editor):

[image: ideal]

In other words, I'd like my `<li>` elements to have their width adjusted to their content with extra padding, while child `<a>` elements still take up 100% of `<li>` space. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this 
nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding:10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

Comment: @FaranAli That causes sides of links to overlap like [this](http://puu.sh/iFeJk.png).

Comment: You can try width, 

nav li:nth-child(2) a  {
    display: block;
   padding:10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

Comment: @FaranAli Doesn't really do anything apart from overlapping by 2nd element only.

Comment: can you give me any live link so I can help you out

Comment: You should look into flexbox.

Comment: @FaranAli Sure, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b15ohacx/1/).

Comment: @Saraph, see my post below. Does removing width and adding padding fix your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

I've updated updated the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dh4hep8r/) that you've posted.

---

You need to change your `a` element to not have `display:block` (should be `inline` instead). Also, you don't need to specify `width` and `height` of `100%`. Just make your `padding: 15px` for the `a`, and you'll have equal, well-spaced hover padding.

I adapted your code above and put it into a codepen, see here:

http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/BNJZoL

Here is how I changed your CSS:

```
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

nav li a {
        padding-left: 15px; ** add padding to both sides
        padding-right: 15px;
        display: inline;
}

nav li :hover {
    background-color: brown;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: `a` is by default `display:inline`, so writing `display:inline` in `a`, it is just redundant

Comment: @dippas That's very cool to know. Don't know how `display: block;` got there in first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try using table layout

```css
body {margin:0}
nav ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}

nav li a {
    background: #fafafa;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;/*or whatever*/
}

nav li :hover {
    background-color: brown;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Very long item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```